# How to plot graph from the uploaded xy text file in drupal

Tags: plot, drupal, graph, drupal-7

I'm trying to plot a graph from the data in the uploaded x-y text file. I tried with the chart module in drupal. But I'm not able to add the correct fields. 
[Current settings that I have given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY62I.png)

My input data looks like the below table

```
Wavelength  Reflectance
350  0.355455189943314 
351  0.326526999473572 
352  0.334652096033096 
353  0.337055295705795 
354  0.331928372383118 
355  0.333575010299683 
356  0.326763778924942 
357  0.322887927293777 
358  0.324449151754379 
359  0.32503405213356 
360  0.323206871747971 
361  0.320580929517746 
362  0.318834781646729 
363  0.319019764661789 
364  0.319294780492783 
365  0.318661510944366 
366  0.31734961271286 
367  0.318917959928513 
368  0.318584978580475 
369  0.317144513130188 
370  0.317843556404114 
371  0.317829728126526 
372  0.319116085767746 
373  0.32110458612442 
374  0.320046484470367 
375  0.319196909666061 
376  0.319480240345001 
377  0.320771843194962 
378  0.321763813495636
```

I tried to plot, but the plots are coming like below
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFoGc.png)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: did you tried google charts ? of C3/D3 js ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [VisualN](https://www.drupal.org/project/visualn) module (Drupal 8 only). You can create a field and set the type of chart you need.
First you will need to create a Visualization style (Configuration > Media > Visualization styles) and then select it when uploading the file. If you don't find a chart type required, you can create a custom Drawer plugin and use it.